# Merging unreachable vertices in DAG may create cycle?

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort

I have a DAG ( directed acyclic graph ) , in which I need to merge some vertices which are unreachable from each other. My final graph should be DAG. My question is by doing this operation, do the final graph can have cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do merges one pair at a time, rechecking reachability after each one, then, no, it's impossible to introduce a cycle, because it would necessarily involve the merged vertices, which means that its arcs would induce a path in the original graph.

Otherwise, it's possible that the transformed graph will have a cycle.

```
A    B
|    |
|    |
v    v
B    A
```

Merge the `A`s. Merge the `B`s.

Comment: Thanks David. But before merging B's if I merge only if there is no path between A and B in the new graph, then it should be fine. Right?

Comment: @quartz Yeah, one pair at a time is fine.